# Adding files to Qrc ressources

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have added a jpg file to the QRC ressources to not drag everytime the full path of the image file.

However, it's not displayed when I am starting the user interface where it's supposed to be loaded!!

I added to it an alias. It's not working. But when I write the name of the file included in the project solution, it's well displayed.

**PS: I want to organize my project and put the file in QRC ressources**

This is how did I do:

```
QPixmap img(":/projet/image.jpg"); // It's not loaded
QPixmap img("image.jpg"); // It's OK
```

Comment: Have you also compiled your Qrc file?

Comment: @vahancho
I have rebuid everything

Comment: Ok, but maybe showing the qrc file and your project file will make sense too?

Comment: A silly point but are you sure the directory's name is projet and not project?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal
Of course, my project's name is PROJET, which is in french btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your .qrc file first.

You can check your file with another editor like notepad++, vim , joe etc.

Does it look similar to this example:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/project">
        <file>FOLDER/image.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

If it does you can access your image through:

```
QPixmap example(":/project/FOLDER/image.jpg");
```

Good luck!

Comment: how to check my qrc file? I am just having a resource file in which, as soon as I open, I get an editor interface, where I have already added to it the image.

Comment: You can open your .qrc file in a native editor (notepad, vim, joe etc.) depending on your operating system, there you can see the .qrc file in plain text.